# How to move an anonymous function out

Tags: jquery

I have a $.ajax call with an error callback:

```
error: function(result){
$('#msg').text(result.statusText).addClass('err');
}
```

I'd like to change it to a more generic:

```
error: myError(result)
```

And then all by itself:

```
function myError(theError){
$('#msg').text(theError.statusText).addClass('err');
}
```

But firebug is telling me "result" is not defined.

Q: Do I call it this way?

```
error: function(result){
myError(result);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just want the function name, not any parenthesis or arguments, like this:

```
error: myError
```

It'll call that function reference with the same arguments as it would an anonymous function, right now it's trying to actually execute the function (with `result` as an argument...a variable it can't find) and assign the *result* as an `error` handler, you want the function itself to actually run *as* the error handler.

Comment: Nick,

Have you considered writing a book?

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn -I'm not that creative :) I just code stuff =P